# Stepper Motor Running (too) Smoothly

Tags: stepper-motor

I acquired two large bipolar stepper motors a couple of years ago. One, I briefly dismantled and then put back together. Now, when I come to use them, the one I took apart doesn't work, and when I rotate the shaft manually, I can't 'feel' the steps. It's just really smooth.

I know that the driver works as it works with it's identical twin which I didn't take apart. A brief glance inside both motors seems that no bits have gone missing...

Any Ideas what part of the stepper I may not have put back right or is it an electrical problem?

Answer (score 3):

You probably (mostly) demagnetized the rotor. It's a nice paperweight now.